# Octave while/for statement -- what's wrong in a code?

Tags: while-loop, octave

This is my Octave code

```
    for K= 1:10
    while ( p < 1 )
        ceil(log2(K))  +  1/(1-(1-p)^K) %function
        p = p + sens;
        K
    endwhile;
 endfor

 K
```

and here is an output:

```
ans =  10.000
K =  1
ans =  5.0000
K =  1
ans =  3.3333
K =  1
ans =  2.5000
K =  1
ans =  2
K =  1
ans =  1.6667
K =  1
ans =  1.4286
K =  1
ans =  1.2500
K =  1
ans =  1.1111
K =  1
ans =  1
K =  1
K =  10
```

So, as you can see -- in inner `while` statement value of `K` is fixed to 1. What I am supposed to do to vary this value between 1 and 10. Why it is not working? I have no idea why this inner `while` statement is proceed only once.

ANSWER: There should be p= initial_value after `for K=`...

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you solved this?

Comment: Or show the final code?

Answer (score 2):

There should be `p= initial_value` after `for K=...`
That is, like this:

```
for K = 1:10
    p = somevalue;
    while ( p < 1 )
    ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this?? How exactly would it look like??

Comment: I edited the answer like I think the OP wanted it to look like.